# Not getting updates from an array of SwiftUI Views In UIKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have an array of views that I am adding to UIKit with UIHostingController. Tapping on a view it increases its count and I want to register this back in my UIKit environment using publisher. However the change does not come through to the UIKit environment. 
Any help would be appreciated.

**UIKit ViewController to import the SwiftUI**

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var cancelablesSet:[AnyCancellable] = []
    var tiles:[ Tile] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                        for i in 0...3{
                    let aTile = Tile(counter: 0, index: i )
                    tiles.append( aTile )
                }
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
                
                let testVC = UIHostingController(rootView: TilesView(tiles: tiles ) )

// function to add view controller as Child
                addChildViewContorller( testVC ) 

                testVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                
                    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                        testVC.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor ),
                        testVC.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor ),
                        testVC.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor ),
                        testVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor ),
                    ])
                

        tiles.publisher.sink(receiveValue: { tile in
            print( "updated tile at index:\(tile.index) to value:\( tile.counter )")
        }).store(in: &cancelablesSet )
    }
}
```

**The SwiftUI View that takes an array of SwiftUI Views**

```
class Tile:Identifiable, ObservableObject{
    enum dicValues{
        case index, counter
    }
    var id:UUID = UUID()
    var index:Int
    @Published var counter:Int
    var isSelected:Bool = false
    
    init(counter: Int = 0, index:Int = -1) {
        self.counter = counter
        self.index = index

    }
}
struct TilesView: View {
    var tiles:[Tile]
    var body: some View {
        ForEach( tiles.indices, id:\.self ){ index in
            TileView( tile: tiles[ index ] )
        }
    }
}

struct TileView: View {
    @ObservedObject var tile:Tile
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill( tile.isSelected ? Color.red : Color.yellow )
                .frame(height: 50)
                .padding( .horizontal )
                .padding( .vertical, 5 )
            Text( "\(tile.counter)")
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold ))
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            tile.counter += 1
            tile.isSelected.toggle()
        }
     }
}
```

Here is the full project code sample if anyone is interested:
[Code sample](https://www.sticklets.co/code/SimpleTransferWithArray.zip)

Comment: Could you please share the code of the Tile?

Comment: Are you sure didn’t forget to add @Publisher wrapper to your property in the Tile?

Comment: I have added the code for the Tile. Thanks for pointing it out.  I do have a @Publisher in my Tile Code, see code.

Comment: Does it work if you make: `var tiles:[ Tile] = []` a `@Published` and use `$tiles.sink` instead of `tiles.publisher.sink`?

Comment: I tried it and it did not work. I have attached the project code at the end of my post if you are interested to have a look. Thanks